# How to calculate inventory value using the FIFO (first-in-first-out) method in R?

Tags: r

I have multiple inventories and keep track of goods (volume) coming in & out.

I need to calculate inventory values (taking profit into account) using the FIFO method.

```
  Inventory       Time Type Price Volume            
1         A 2015-07-15  BUY  7.50      4            
2         A 2015-07-20  BUY  7.69      2            
3         A 2015-07-21  BUY  7.40      1            
4         A 2015-07-24  BUY  7.26      2            
5         A 2015-07-30 SELL  7.35      8            
6         A 2015-07-31  BUY  7.92      2            
7         B 2015-09-15  BUY  8.50      3            
8         B 2015-09-21  BUY  8.20      5            
9         B 2015-09-28 SELL  9.25      6
```

For example:

The sell on date 2015-07-30 (8 units) had a FIFO cost of:

4 x 7.5 + 2 x 7.69 + 1 x 7.4 + 1 x 7.26 = 60.04

Thus profit (loss):

8*7.35 – 60.04 = -1.24

Value of goods left in Inventory A after the transaction:
1 x 7.26 + 2 x 7.92 = 23.1

Inventory value after adjusting for loss: 23.1 + (-1.24)  = 21.86

How can I use R to calculate portfolio values for each inventory separately?

Code for example table:

```
df1 <- data.frame(Inventory = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B"),
                             Time = c("2015-07-15", "2015-07-20", "2015-07-21", "2015-07-24", "2015-07-30", "2015-07-31", "2015-09-15", "2015-09-21", "2015-09-28"),
                             Type = c("BUY", "BUY", "BUY", "BUY", "SELL", "BUY", "BUY", "BUY", "SELL"),
                             Price = c(7.5, 7.69, 7.4, 7.26, 7.35, 7.92, 8.5, 8.2, 9.25),
                             Volume = c(4, 2, 1, 2, 8, 2, 3, 5, 6))
```

Comment: One possibility could be to split your df into two: one with buys only, the other with sells. Then transform the buys into rows of 1 item each, so that you get 4 rows for item A for July 15, etc. You can then join this expanded table with the sell table by inventory column where date of buy is less than date of sell and cumulative sum of buys = items sold. Working out the P/L is easy then?

Comment: I understand your idea, but I'll be dealing with transactions (stock trades in blocks, actually) that are in 10,000s. So the calculation could get expensive.

Comment: Will there never be more than one BUY or SELL event per date?

Comment: There can be more BUYs and SELLs on each date. There is also a timestamp (HH:MM:SS) column